# If object rotated, other objects vanishing! p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm a beginner in p5.js. This is my code till now:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
 background(50, 168, 82);
 road();
 sidepath();
 truck();
 house();
 tree();
}

function road() {
 fill(66, 62, 61);
 noStroke();
 rect(200, 0, 220, 600);

 fill(197, 222, 202);
 rect(300, 50, 40, 70);
 rect(300, 200, 40, 70);
 rect(300, 350, 40, 70);
 rect(300, 500, 40, 70);
}

function sidepath() {
 fill(67, 230, 80);
 rect(0, 0, 220, 600);
 rect(400, 0, 220, 600);
}

function house() {
 fill(245, 225, 110);
 rect(80, 50, 55, 55, 3);
 triangle(80, 50, 45, 80, 80, 105);

 fill(67, 230, 80);
 rect(92, 60, 30, 30); 
 fill(245, 225, 110);
 translate(width/6, height/120);
 rotate(PI/3.5);
 rect(5, 45, 13, 64, 3);
 translate(width/5, height/90);
 rotate(PI/2.4);
 rect(60, 63, 13, 64, 3);
}

function tree() {
 fill(78, 150, 84);
 triangle(70, 420, 30, 450, 70, 480);
 triangle(100, 410, 50, 450, 100, 490);
 triangle(130, 400, 75, 450, 130, 500);
 rect(130, 430, 38, 30);
}
```

Even if I put the tree, it doesn't appear **because** I've used **rotate** in my **house**. If you comment on the rotating part, the tree appears. Can I, however, get both of them?

Answer (score 2):

Operations like [`rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate) and [`translate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate) define a new transformation matrix and multiply the current matrix with the new matrix.
If you only want to apply a rotation to 1 object, you must save the current matrix with [`push`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) before specifying the rotation, and restore the matrix with [`pop`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop) after you have driven the object.

Pseudo code:

```js
push()
roatate(...)

// [...] draw object (e.g. rect())

pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your calling functions such as `rotate()` and `translate()`, without a `push()` or a `pop()` to store that data. The `rotate()` and `translate` also rotate and translate the tree because those two functions affect everything after it's called. The way to fix this is using `push()` and `pop()` I would recommend learning about these functions first because they are very useful.

```
 function house() {
 fill(245, 225, 110);
 rect(80, 50, 55, 55, 3);
 triangle(80, 50, 45, 80, 80, 105);

 fill(67, 230, 80);
 rect(92, 60, 30, 30); 
 fill(245, 225, 110);
push();
 translate(width/6, height/120);
 rotate(PI/3.5);
 rect(5, 45, 13, 64, 3);
 translate(width/5, height/90);
 rotate(PI/2.4);
 rect(60, 63, 13, 64, 3);
pop();
}
```

I've simply just added in a `push()` and a `pop()` so the `rotate` and `translate` only affect the house. I would recommend reading this [page](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and reading this [page](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop) They should sum up what `push()` and `pop()` do.

If you have any questions, I'd be glad to clarify.